# DB2 Grant Permissions (like SELECT/INSERT/etc) to all tables of a schema

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am currently working on some DB2 work which requires me to grant the following privileges to all the tables within a schema:

`GRANT
  SELECT,
  INDEX,
  INSERT,
  UPDATE,
  DELETE,
  CREATE,
  DROP,
  ALTER,
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
ON MY_SCRATCH_SCHEMA.* to 'MY_USER'@'%';`

The above is a query for MySQL, however, I need to rewrite it for DB2.

As far as I know, there's no command to grant those permissions to all tables of a schema, you must rely on a procedure. But knowing it's DB2, there's documentation that's all over the place that works for different versions of DB2, so I am a little not trusting of what's online.

So my question is - how do I rewrite the above query for DB2?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to it thru QUery is DB2. Either you create a stored procedure or you do it manually. You can do the following too

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT, INDEX, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, 
DROP, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON ' || 
trim(system_table_schema)||'.'||trim(system_table_name) || 'TO USERID WITH GRANT OPTION ;'
 FROM QSYS2.systables WHERE SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA ='SCHEMANAME'
```

Run the above query and then copy the result and run the result. Hope this helps. FOr a lot of userids, you can add them to a group and provide the authoity to that group name

Comment: Hey - I gave your answer a try, and received the following two errors: `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=QSYS2.SYSTABLES, DRIVER=4.16.53 [SQL State=42704, DB Errorcode=-204] 
Next: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;QSYS2.SYSTABLES, DRIVER=4.16.53 [SQL State=56098, DB Errorcode=-727]`. Any ideas why? I tried simply `SELECT * FROM QSYS2.systables` and it doesn't appear that table exists.

Comment: I guess your tables ae catalouged in different table, You will need the master table.

Comment: what do I need to change within your script and how do I find the master table? Thank you!

Comment: I checked my tables, and here are the following that start with `SYS`: https://puu.sh/vfOLY/4426b532ce.png

Answer (score 1):

I adapted uSeruSher's answer to this. For some reason, `QSYS2.systables` doesn't exist in my instance of DB2, but `SYSIBM.TABLES` exists which I found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm).

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT, INDEX, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, 
DROP, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON ' || 
trim(table_schema)||'.'||trim(table_name) || 'TO USERID WITH GRANT OPTION ;'
 FROM SYSIBM.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='SCHEMANAME'
```